# AppendChild in `for` loop or `forEach `

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, appendchild

I have several classes with `single-product` as className. I am trying to add the buttons to all of them using `appendChild` in `for loop` in javascript. But it doesn't seem to be working. I don't understand why?
I am taking them in an array using `querySelectorAll`.
`let products = document.querySelectorAll('.single-products')` then I created an element `div` which contains my button.

```
let button = document.createElement('div');
button.innerHTML = "<a class='btn hero-btn'>Add to cart</a>";
for (let i=0 ; i < products.length ; i++){document.querySelectorAll('.single-product')[i].appendChild(button.cloneNode())
```

I also tried `forEach` with `this` as the param but even that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program would never enter the loop and it also generates ReferenceError because `products` is never defined to find it's length. You have to define it before the program enters the for loop. And the other thing is `cloneNode()` only creates the clone at the base level. You have to use `cloneNode(true)` to clone it and it's descendents as well. Here is the fix for your code:

```
let button = document.createElement("div");

button.innerHTML = "<a class='btn hero-btn'>Add to cart</a>";

let products = document.querySelectorAll(".single-product");

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].appendChild(button.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `cloneNode()` with `true` to clone along with its descendants/children.
Also first get the list of elements once, and then iterate through it and append the button, like.

```
let button = document.createElement('div');
button.innerHTML = "<a class='btn hero-btn'>Add to cart</a>";

let productSections = document.querySelectorAll('.single-product');
for (let i=0 ; i < productSections.length ; i++){
   productSections[i].appendChild(button.cloneNode(true));
)
```